# spring-statemachine 2.3.1 - How to get a StateMachine from a StateMachineModelFactory?

Tags: spring-statemachine

I'm having the following business case while working with spring-statemachine 2.3.1 in a project:

The state machine is defined with the Papyrus plugin and loaded from an uml file using the UmlStateMachineModelFactory as shown below:

```
public class MyStateMachineConfig extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<String, String>
{
  @Override
  public void configure(StateMachineModelConfigurer<String, String> model) throws Exception
  {
    model.withModel().factory(myStateMachineModelFactory());
  }

  @Bean
  public StateMachineModelFactory<String, String> myStateMachineModelFactory()
  {
    return new UmlStateMachineModelFactory("classpath:my.uml");
  }
  ....
```

I need to persist the state machine context in a database using JPA. In order to do this, I need to use StateMachinePersister.persist(). This method uses as its first input parameter a StateMachine instance. However, I'm not able to get the StateMachine instance from my StateMachineModelFactory. The class StateMachineFactory has a method named getStateMachine() while the class StateMachineModelFactory doesn't.

I didn't find neither a way to get a StateMachineFactory instance from a StateMachineModelFactory instance. Could anyone please help with some suggestions, ideally examples ? The documentation has different examples of how to do it but none for the case when the state machine is loaded from an UML file.

Kind regards,

Nicolas DUMINIL

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration for StateMachineFactory should look like below

```
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachineFactory
public static class SsmConfig
        extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<States, Events> {

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, Events> states)
            throws Exception {
        states
            .withStates()
                .initial(States.S1)
                .end(States.SF)
                .states(EnumSet.allOf(States.class));
    }

}
```

And then you can simply inject StateMachineFactory everywhere and just get `state machine`.

```
class SomeService {

    @Autowired
    private StateMachineFactory<States, Events> factory;

    void method() {
        StateMachine<States,Events> stateMachine = factory.getStateMachine();
        stateMachine.start();
    }
}
```

More information can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#sm-factories).

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration, which extends `StateMachineConfigurerAdapter` is an "adaptation" or modification of the auto-configured Spring state machine.

In order for your configuration to be picked-up by spring you need to annotate it with `@Configuration`.

You also have to enable the State Machine auto-configuration, which happens with `@EnableStateMachie` annotation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachine
public class MyStateMachineConfig extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<String, String> {
```

You can refer to [the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/index.html#using-code-umlstatemachinemodelfactory-code) for more details.

Once this is active, you can inject the StateMachine as a dependency.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I see there is also a EnableStateMachineFactory annotation, right ? And one can name them, for example StateMachine(name="myStateMachine") and then Bean @Qualifier("myStateMachine) private StateMachine myStateMachine;
Is that correct ?

Comment: The EnableStateMachineFactory exposes a factory for State Machines (SMs) - you can inject it and get multiple SM instances. Yes - you can give names or qualifiers to the Beans - this is done in case you have multiple instances of the same bean types, so you can clarify (providing the name) which instance exactly you want to be injected - otherwise if you have multiple instances and no qualifiers Spring doesn't know which one to inject as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks again for the update. My use case requires to manage JPA entities having a life cycle described by a state machine. To implement it, I'm trying to use the sample here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/tree/master/spring-statemachine-samples/datapersist/src/main/java/demo/datapersist. This sample uses Spring Data repositories and the StateMachineJackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean  to populate the state machine repository from a JSON file. However, in my case, the state machine has been modeled in UML, via the Payrus tool. How could I populate the repository ?